# Column width of Table.Column.EXPAND_COLUMN in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

[image]How to change the width of expander column in antd table, I am able to add background color to it but not able to change the width
I am using @pankod/refine-antd as the framework

**column data for antd table**

```
 const columns = [
    {
      title: "Hero Image",
      dataIndex: "image",
      key: "image",
      width: "10%",
      render: (value) => (
        <ImageField
          value={value}
          width={100}
          style={{
            border: "1px solid #919EAB",
            background: "#FFFFFF",
            padding: "10px",
            filter: "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)",
          }}
        />
      ),
    },
    Table.EXPAND_COLUMN,
    {
      title: "Title",
      dataIndex: "title",
      key: "title",
      width: "10%",
      render: (value) => <TextField value={value} />,
      sorter: (a, b) => a.title.length - b.title.length,
    },
]


       return(
          <Table
            pagination={{ defaultPageSize: 20, hideOnSinglePage: true }}
            expandable={{
              expandedRowRender: (record) => {
                    return (
              <div className="expaneded-column-container">
                <Row gutter={16}>
                  <Col span={5} className="d-flex-col">
                   .
                   .
                   </Col>
                  </Row>
                 </div>
                )
               }
             }}
             />
          [![Column in yellow takes the width as 349px. I am not able to set the width of the column expander][1]][1])
```

**Applying style using className does not work**

```
.ant-table-row-expand-icon-cell {
  width: 50px !important;
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```